# Delete file on ftp server with pycurl

Tags: python, ftp, libcurl, pycurl

Is it possible to delete a file on ftp server in python with the pycurl-lib?

My code so far, but not working, it throws: (21, 'QUOT command failed with 550')

```
    c = pycurl.Curl()
    c.setopt(pycurl.URL, 'ftp://ftpadress/testdirectory')
    c.setopt(pycurl.USERPWD, 'user:pass')
    c.setopt(pycurl.QUOTE, ['DELE test.txt'])
    c.perform()
    c.close()
```

Comment: If Curl really strips the actual error message issued by the server for 550 code, check the log file to see it. + Did you try deleting the file using a GUI/command-line FTP client?

Comment: Set `VERBOSE` to see the full interaction...

Answer (score 0):

It worked with changing the "DELE test.txt" into the full path from base.
Like:

```
    c = pycurl.Curl()
    c.setopt(pycurl.URL, 'ftp://ftpadress')
    c.setopt(pycurl.USERPWD, 'user:pass')
    c.setopt(pycurl.QUOTE, ['DELE testdirectory/test.txt'])
    c.perform()
    c.close()
```

Comment: See: [CURLOPT_FTP_FILEMETHOD](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_FTP_FILEMETHOD.html)